# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './lib/axios'

Tags: typescript, webpack, axios

I'm trying to import axios in my project. However, for some reasons, webpack/axios is causing me big troubles when trying to build.

**GroupService.ts**

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse, AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
```

**webpack --display-error-details** errors

```
ERROR in ./~/axios/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './lib/axios' in 'C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\axios'
resolve './lib/axios' in 'C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\axios'
  using description file: C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\axios\package.json (relative path: .)
  after using description file: C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\axios\package.json (relative path: .)
    using description file: C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\axios\package.json (relative path: ./lib/axios)
      as directory
        C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\axios\lib\axios doesn't exist
      no extension
        C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\axios\lib\axios doesn't exist
      .ts
        C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\axios\lib\axios.ts doesn't exist
[C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\axios\lib\axios]
[C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\axios\lib\axios]
[C:\dev\test-project\node_modules\axios\lib\axios.ts]
 @ ./~/axios/index.js 1:17-39
 @ ./src/services/GroupService.ts
 @ ./src/test-project.ts
```

Here's my webpack configurations.

**webpack.config.js**

```
/** Plugin settings **/
var jsOutputFile = 'dist/testproject.min.js';
var cssOutputFile = 'dist/styles.css';

/** Webpack configuration **/
var webpack = require("webpack");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin(cssOutputFile);

module.exports = {
  // application entry file
  entry: "./src/test-project.ts",

  // bundled application output file
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: jsOutputFile
  },

  // Currently we need to add '.ts' to the resolve.extensions array.
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts']
  },

  // Source maps support ('inline-source-map' also works)
  devtool: 'source-map',

  // Add the loader for .ts files.
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: extractCSS.extract([
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ])
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: true
      }
    }),
    extractCSS
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Webpack can not find an entry point for axios, because try to search typescript file, but there is no such file. You should add .js to the resolve extensions. More information here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions

```js
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and the following command solved my problem.

```
npm install --save axios
```

Answer (score 8):

For me the problem was that I didn't restart the `yarn start` service after installing axios the library was correctly installed in the app local `node_modules` directory.

### Solution

Stopped the yarn service with <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> and restarted it again with `yarn start`.

Comment: Tyvm! I was searching for ages. After seeing your answer and restarting the app, no errors!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:

> module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'axios' in '

I realized that axios folder in not found in the node_module folder of my project. I had already used `npm install --save axios` but it was still not found in my local node-module folder.

This is how I solved this issue. I looked for some other react projects I had already done and copied the axios folder in the node_module folder of that old project. I later pasted the copied axios folder into the node_module folder of my current project and the problem varnished.

Answer (score 0):

Pls remember to run **"npm eject"(to stop the server)** before you install axios.
This is how I resolve this problem

```
npm eject
npm install --save axios
```